# How to remove building warning message in xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to see the only compiler error in my debug section
[image]

Comment: Write better code. Read the warnings carefully. Some of them suggest fixes. Avoid `Any` and optionals as much as possible and unwrap optionals safely.

Comment: thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter Issues to show only errors by selecting option at the bottom of the navigator. Check this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlQvY.png).

Comment: Thanks for your help :D